# In Excel: Trying to get the first visible value in a column from a table

Tags: excel

I am trying to get the first(or last) visible value from a table on another sheet. I am trying to retrieve it from Sheet1. I have tried using

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/Sheet1!E:E<>),Sheet1!E:E)
```

which returns the last value regardless of it being visible or not after a filter is applied.  I have also tried

```
 =VLOOKUP("*",Sheet1!E:E,1,FALSE)
```

which will give me the first value in the column- but that is the name of the column. Is there a way to skip the first value in the VLOOKUP equation? Thanks for any help.

Comment: That is returning the value in the first cell with data in the column, but when I filter that column and that cell is not visible, it still shows the same value.  For example: The column in the Table is labeled STUDENT NAMES. The first name in that column is Don. I filter for another student named James in the table but the returned value is still Don. Dons data is on row 3 and James is on row 12.  Thanks gpullen and pnuts.

Comment: Sorry, thats as clear as my non existent excel vocabulary would let me be. I'm probably making this a lot harder because of that.